# Dynamically select div by dynamically created id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, jquery-selectors

I created a function that creates a HTML chunk of code. Its ids are created dynamically with a tag variable collected from a form. Code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#addTag").click(function() {
    var tag = $("#tag").val();
    $('section').append('<div id="galleryContainer' + tag + '"><div class=".gallery-header"><h1 >Tag:' + tag + '</h1><div class=".gallery-sort"><p>Sort by:</p><button onclick="sortImagesByPublishedDate()" >Data published</button><button onclick="sortImagesByTakenDate()">Data taken</button><div data-tag="' + tag + '" class="gallery component" id="' + tag + '"></div></div></div></div>');
    mainFunction(tag);
  });
});
```

Then I want to use `sortImagesByPublishedDate()` and  `sortImagesByTakenDate()` by clicking a button, but I want them to sort images only in this particular gallery and not in all galleries. If I have one gallery, it works fine. Problems begin when I add more galleries. How should I select the variable `$gallery` in the following functions?

```
function sortImagesByPublishedDate() {
  var $gallery = $('div.gallery'),
    $galleryA = $gallery.children('a');

  $galleryA.sort(function(a, b) {
    var an = a.getAttribute('data-published'),
      bn = b.getAttribute('data-published');

    if (an > bn) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (an < bn) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  $galleryA.detach().appendTo($gallery);
}
```

Comment: What element are you trying to get, the `.gallery` div that is next to the buttons in your generated html?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. How should I do that?

Comment: Pass `this` to `sortImagesByPublishedDate(this)` so your code is `function sortImagesByPublishedDate(thisObj) {` and then do `var $gallery = $(thisObj).closest(".gallery");`

Comment: @DominikGłowicki check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [.siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method to select elements that are siblings of another element. So in your case you can just call

```
var $gallery = $(buttonElement).siblings(".gallery");
```

Since you are using inline JS to call the sort functions you need to modify it to pass `this` to your functions that way you can get a reference to the button that was clicked, ie:

Modified html

```
<button onclick="sortImagesByPublishedDate(this)">Date published</button>
```

JS

```
function sortImagesByPublishedDate(ele){
  var $gallery = $(ele).siblings(".gallery"),
```

Demo

```js
$(function(){
  $("#addTag").click(function(){
    var tag=$("#tag").val();
    $('section').append('<div id="galleryContainer'+tag+'"><div class=".gallery-header"><h1 >Tag:'+tag+'</h1><div class=".gallery-sort"><p>Sort by:</p><button onclick="sortImagesByPublishedDate(this)" >Data published</button><button onclick="sortImagesByTakenDate(this)">Data taken</button><div data-tag="'+tag+'" class="gallery component" id="'+tag+'"></div></div></div></div>');
    //mainFunction(tag);
  });
});

function sortImagesByPublishedDate(ele){
  var $gallery = $(ele).siblings(".gallery"),
      $galleryA = $gallery.children('a');
  alert($gallery[0].id);

  $galleryA.sort(function(a,b){
    var an = a.getAttribute('data-published'),
        bn = b.getAttribute('data-published');

    if(an > bn) {
      return 1;
    }
    if(an < bn) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  $galleryA.detach().appendTo($gallery);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tag">
<button id="addTag">Add</button>
<section>
</section>
```

Instead of inline js you could use [delegated event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) handling to have listeners setup for your buttons:

Modified html

```
<button class="sortButton" data-sort="date">Data published</button>
<button class="sortButton" data-sort="taken">Data taken</button>
```

JS

```
$("section").on("click",".sortButton",function(){
   //'this' will be the button clicked
   var $gallery = $(this).siblings(".gallery");
   var sortBy = $(this).data("sort");
   if(sortBy == "date"){
        //do date sort
   } else if(sortBy == "taken"){
        //do taken sort
   }
   //... rest of code
});
```

Comment: IT WORKS GREAT. THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I think this will worl:

HTML:

```
sortImagesByPublishedDate(this)//pass this
```

JS:

```
  function sortImagesByPublishedDate() {
  var $gallery = $(this).siblings('.gallery'),
  $galleryA = $gallery.children('a');
           .
           .
```

Comment: It doesn't. I don't understand it. What is second element?

Comment: second sibling from clicked button

Comment: The element might not always be the second from whatever element, you would have to change this code if the position of the .gallery element ever changed. You can use `.siblings()` to select sibling elements

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` to `sortImagesByPublishedDate(this)` in your `html` of `append`

so your code is

`function sortImagesByPublishedDate(thisObj) {`

and then do

`var $gallery = $(thisObj).siblings(".gallery");`

Comment: @DominikGłowicki it gets work. only change to `siblings`

Comment: @DominikGłowicki sorry for closest finding i missed that you are having `.gallery` in same sibling. it works with `this` as i mentioned first in comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#addTag").click(function() {
        var tag = $("#tag").val();
        $('section').append('<div id="galleryContainer' + tag + '"><div class=".gallery-header"><h1 >Tag:' + tag + '</h1><div class=".gallery-sort"><p>Sort by:</p><button onclick="sortImagesByPublishedDate()" >Data published</button><button onclick="sortImagesByTakenDate()">Data taken</button><div data-tag="' + tag + '" class="gallery component" id="' + tag + '"></div></div></div></div>');
        sortImagesByPublishedDate(tag);  **// call the function and pass param tag**
        mainFunction(tag);
    });
});

function sortImagesByPublishedDate(tag) {
    **// instead of class select id**
    var $gallery = $('div#galleryContainer'+tag),
        $galleryA = $gallery.children('a');

    $galleryA.sort(function(a, b) {
        var an = a.getAttribute('data-published'),
            bn = b.getAttribute('data-published');

        if (an > bn) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (an < bn) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    $galleryA.detach().appendTo($gallery);
}
```

// hope this helps